# Where did I make a mistake in the Mergesort algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm

I'm learning some algorithm and at the moment I try to implement Mergesort into Java. This is my code:

```
public class Mergesort {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int []a = {12,34,6543,3,6,45,23,677,56,67,3,4,54,5};
    sort(a);
    for(int i:a)
    {
        System.out.println(i);
    }

}
private static void merge(int[]a,int[]b,int[]c)
{
    int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0; 
    while((i < b.length) && (j < c.length))
    {
        if(b[i] < c[j])
        {
            a[k++] = b[i++];   
        }
        else
        {
            a[k++] = c[j++];
        }

        while( i < b.length)
        {
            a[k++] = b[i++];
        }

        while( j < c.length)
        {
            a[k++] = c[j++];
        }
    }

}

public static void sort (int[]a)
{
        if(a.length > 1)
    {

    int m = a.length / 2;
    int[]b = new int[m];
    int[]c = new int[a.length-m];

    for(int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        b[i] = a[i];
    }
    for(int i = m; i <a.length; i++ )
    {
        c[i-m] = a[i];
    }

    sort(b);
    sort(c);

    merge(a,b,c);
    }
}
}
```

This is the output:

```
6543
6
23
45
56
677
67
4
5
54
```

I copy this from a tutorial but I dont know where the mistake is. My second question is:

What does this mean: a[k++] == b[i++];

I know that we are changing the value of a[k] ( k = position in a) to  b[i] but why the ++?

I thought this mean that you are increasing the value by 1?
Thank you for reading.

Comment: a[k++] = b[i++] is the same as : a[k]=b[i];k=k+1;i=i+1;

Comment: re: your second question, without being elaborate about it `k++` means read value of k then increment it by 1. `++k` means increment k by one and read it.

Comment: the increment operator has already been explained. Regarding the first question, it looks to me like the merge logic is flawed, but please let us know what the input array looks like just to be sure

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: This is the input array:  int []a = {12,34,6543,3,6,45,23,677,56,67,3,4,54,5};

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your merge routine is wrong. The second and third while loops should **not** be inside the first while loop. They should be outside it.

The first while loop compares items of the two arrays until there are no more elements left in one of them.
Only after it is done, the second and third loops should come into play.

The second and third loops (only one of them actually does any work in any invocation of merge) handle the remainder of the array that contains the highest values.

Therefore it should look like this :

```
private static void merge(int[]a,int[]b,int[]c)
{
    int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0; 
    while((i < b.length) && (j < c.length))
    {
        if(b[i] < c[j])
        {
            a[k++] = b[i++];   
        }
        else
        {
            a[k++] = c[j++];
        }
    }
    while( i < b.length)
    {
        a[k++] = b[i++];
    }

    while( j < c.length)
    {
        a[k++] = c[j++];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What does this mean:

```
a[k++] == b[i++];
```

++ is the increment operator. See ***Unary Operators*** under [Assignment, Arithmetic, and Unary Operators](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op1.html)

This is equivalent to

```
a = a + 1
```

So

```
a[k++] == b[i++];
```

is same as

```
a[k] == b[i]; 
k = k + 1;
i = i + 1;
```

<sub>Wny is my code not working is offtopic. Please debug and ask any specific questions</sub>